# Does styling UI objects in iOS violate MVC?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, ios6, uiviewcontroller

I'm somewhat new to MVC and iOS development, and I can't seem reconcile how UI styling fits into this paradigm.

My view of MVC is built using storyboards, and I can apply primitive styling through Xcode's attribute inspector, but anything more complicated I have to use the Controller to style.  For example:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; // required

    // set background color of view
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
}
```

This seems to be a clear violation of MVC, as I'm applying style logic inside of the controller's code.  I find this analogous to writing an HTML app and instead of using style sheets, I write code to apply styles locally in JavaScript.  Is this a weakness of iOS or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: You can mix and match the two within your code. If you want you can even manipulate Model details in the Controller as well. The MVC is not strictly enforced in the general guidelines of the pattern, but if you want to stay true to the paradigm you just have to refrain from using M or V in C.

Comment: One could argue that style is a form of data. Since a controller normally supplies a view with data, having the controller supply the view with style is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) :

> some controller objects might also tell a view object to change an
>   aspect of its appearance or behavior

And it does make sense as the view is supposed to be passive and only reflect the application state as a UI and the controller will "tell" the view if some of its content needs to be changed according to user actions. (e.g background change, visibility of controls etc...)

Comment: But in this case I'm just styling the look of static buttons, labels, etc.  Has no connection with responding to user actions or a change in the model.  I think iOS might be missing the equivalent of CSS.

Comment: The view must be created somewhere as the view does not invoke its own creation. Though Interface Builder does hide most of this from you does not mean its not creating the views in the same way

Answer (score 1):

Actually the screen is your "view", and your "controller" is sending a message to your view to use a different color for the background.

If you had a data object that held the screen color, that could be your "model".  In that case, you'd be passing the data from your model to the view through the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix and match the two within your code. If you want you can even manipulate Model details in the Controller as well. The MVC is not strictly enforced in the general guidelines of the pattern, but if you want to stay true to the paradigm you just have to refrain from using M or V in C.

View entails cosmetics and aesthetics of the forms as well as styling, but bottom line, you can manipulate these facets from the controller...

Answer (score 0):

As others said, if you understand colors and styles as data, it is ok to let the controller take care for it.

But you also could subclass UIviews and internally set the style.

Let's say, you have a `TrafficLightView : UIView` with a property `id trafficLight`. you could overwrite the setter and set the background color of the view accordingly to the state of the object. `trafficLight.`